# How to initialize IOption<AppSettings> for unit testing a .NET core MVC service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a .NET core MVC rest service. 
I have a controller I wish to test. This controller has a constructor argument of IOptions where AppSettings is my class for config settings ( I store my database connection string in it). It gets injected from the setup in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs

The rest service works. My problem is I've set up a MSTest test project to test the service. I can't figure out how to initialize an instance of IOptions to satisfy the constructor of my controller.

Comment: You might want to look into a mocking framework like NSubstitute or Moq.  This will let you create a mock IOptions object that you can pass into the instance of your controller in the unit tests.

Comment: @IsThatQueeblo I figured out a simple way to initialize an instance of `IOption`   (i posted an answer) however I also need to mock some headers in the Http request. I imagine those mocking frameworks will provide that as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net Core Unit Testing - Mock IOptions<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876507/net-core-unit-testing-mock-ioptionst)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I discovered the answer shortly after posting the question.

use Helper class `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options`

> Creates a wrapper around an instance of TOptions to return itself as
>   IOptions

```
AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings() { ConnectionString = "..." };
IOptions<AppSettings> options = Options.Create(appSettings);
MyController controller = new MyController(options);
```