# Read and use settings from appsettings.json without IOptions<T>?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

.NET Core [allows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects) to lazily read settings from configuration file, de-serialize it to a POCO and register that POCO in built-in DI container with one line of code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MySection"));
}
```

Then any consumer can resolve `IOptions<MyOptions>` to access that POCO:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<MyOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
    MyOptions options = optionsAccessor.Value;
}
```

This approach has the significant disadvantages:

- Unnecessary dependency from `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` package:
- Mocking, testing and explicit instance creation become a bit more verbose.

What is the easiest solution to resolve options without `IOptions<T>`?

Comment: @Set, I read that article https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ and decided to try. The result doesn't look suitable for a good documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deserialize options with `configuration.Get<TOptions>` or `configuration.Bind` call and register a POCO in DI container explicitly as singleton:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingletonFromFile<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MySection"));
}

//...

public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonFromFile<TOptions>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration)
    where TOptions : class, new()
{
    //POCO is created with actual values 
    TOptions options = configuration.Get<TOptions>();

    services.AddSingleton(options);

    return services;
}
```

UPD: thanks to @NPNelson for `.Get<TOptions>()` hint.

Then `IOptions<T>` resolving is no longer needed, and the class dependencies become clear:

```
public HomeController(MyOptions options)
{
    _options = options;
}
```

FYI: reading from an external service (database etc.) is also possible this way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransientFromService<OptionsReader, MyOptions>(reader => reader.GetOptions());
}

//...

public static void AddTransientFromService<TReader, TOptions>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Func<TReader, TOptions> getOptions)
    where TReader : class
    where TOptions : class

{
    services.AddTransient(provider => getOptions(provider.GetService<TReader>()));
}
```

Remarks:

- Singleton is not lazy (it's always instantiated at startup);
- In case of singleton registration, any ability to update options at runtime is lost (.NET Core natively supports runtime file reloading with `reloadOnChange` option setup: `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, reloadOnChange: true)`);

If you *really* need the file reload and you still don't want to use `IOptions`, consider a transient resolving. Of course, per-request resolving can lead to the significant perfomance decrease.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 1.1 and higher, you can use configuration.GetSection("App").Get<TOptions> instead of configuration.Bind(). I find the new approach a little easier to read.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can just mock IOptions if you want to unit test services that depend on it. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876507/net-core-unit-testing-mock-ioptionst). Depending on IOptions is still just depending on an interface, so it's not (or shouldn't be) making your code harder to test.

Comment: Yes, of course. As I said, it is just more verbose. And it still doesn't give a reason for `IOptions` in constructor.

Comment: Moreover, it is not an answer to question.

Comment: Fair enough. 