# Unable to read details from appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm unable to retrieve the value from appsettings.json, when I run the code below, I get an error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**appSettings.json**

```
"MySettings": {
"ConnectionString": "",
"Provider": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
    }
```

**MySettings.cs**

```
public class MySettings 
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static string Provider { get; set; }
}
```

**TestDriveDatabase.cs**

```
public class TestDriveDatabase
{
    private IDatabase objDLOperation;

    public TestDriveDatabase(string strConnectionstring)
    {
        objDLOperation = GetDataLayerInstance(strConnectionstring);
    }
    public IDatabase GetDataLayerInstance(string strConnectionstring)
    {
        IDatabase objInstance = null;
        var provider = MySettings.Provider;

        if (provider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
        {
            objInstance = new SQLDatabase(strConnectionstring);
        }
        else if (provider == "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL")
        {
            objInstance = new PostgreDatabase(strConnectionstring);
        }

        return objInstance;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the mapping from `appsettings.json` to `MySettings` is not happening and the variable `provider` always remains null. Whats wrong here ?

Comment: remove `static` modifier from property. Pass `MySettings` via DI.

Comment: If you remove static, you can't simply access MySettings.Provider

Comment: Of course. How it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43679665/5112433

Comment: @izengod: Mapping only works to instance properties, not to static properties. Second, you are supposed to inject the `MySettings` class into your services (via `IOptions<MySettings>`) instead accessing it's static properties

Comment: @Tseng I was trying out without DI since I am not calling it inside a controller.

Comment: DI works everywhere, as long as the class is resolved by DI at some point. And accessing static values like you did is very bad, for both testability and decoupling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the static keyword, you can't map configuration values to static properties

```
public class MySettings 
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public string Provider { get; set; }
}
```

Second, inject `MySettings` into your `TestDriveDatabase`.

```
public class TestDriveDatabase
{
    private IDatabase objDLOperation;
    private readonly MySettings settings;

    public TestDriveDatabase(IOptions<MySettings> mySettings)
    {
        this.settings = mySettings.Value;
        objDLOperation = GetDataLayerInstance(strConnectionstring);
    }
    public IDatabase GetDataLayerInstance(string strConnectionstring)
    {
        IDatabase objInstance = null;
        var provider = settings.Provider;

        if (provider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
        {
            objInstance = new SQLDatabase(settings.Connectionstring);
        }
        else if (provider == "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL")
        {
            objInstance = new PostgreDatabase(settings.Connectionstring);
        }

        return objInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: cool! but what shall I pass in TestDriveDatabase ctor while creating an instance ? since it takes an IOptions<MySettings> object. I need to call another method of TestDriveDatabase inside controller.

Comment: Use Dependency Injection all the way. The only time you should use the `new` keyword is when you create models or inside factory methods. All other services should be done via DI. That's the whole point of using DI in the first place. i.e. when you define `TestDriveDatabase` in your Controller's ctor, then `IOption<MySettings>` will also be resolved by DI, because `TestDriveDatabase gets resolved by it too.