# Get connection string in Data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a layered architecture for a project as follows.

```
MyProject.Web           <-- ASP.NET Core app
MyProject.BusinessLogic <-- Class Library
MyProject.DataAccess    <-- Class Library
```

`Web` project references `BusinessLogic`, which in turn references `DataAccess`.

The connection string is stored in `appsettings.json` in `Web` project as follows.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LocalDatabase": "Server=..."
  },
  // ...

  }
}
```

How do I get a connection string in the `DataAccess` project?

Comment: `appsettings.json` should be located in application's entry point. Which is web project. Read the connection string at startup and pass it to data layer. Sorry I don't see any problem yet.

Comment: That would mean to read connection string in `Web`, then pass it to `BusinessLogic`, then pass it to `DataAccess`. This does not look very good.

Comment: You could use DI to make it cleaner: register a DTO and resolve it in the data layer. For example http://stackoverflow.com/q/43679665/5112433

Comment: @erdinger: You don't need to pass the connection string. You configure a `DbOptionsBuilder<TDbContext>`, this is what happens behind `.AddDbContext<T>` method. It is registered with DI and injected into the DbContext when its resolved (or you can do it manually by requesting DbOptionsBuilder via DI and pass it to your context (and modify it before if necessary). Ideally you don't need to pass it anyways, most cases are covered with AddDBContext inside startup.cs

Comment: @Tseng, thanks. However, I'm not using EF, I'm using Dapper in the `DataAccess`.

Comment: You may wish to consider restructuring your application to follow the Dependency Inversion Principle and Clean Architecture. http://deviq.com/dependency-inversion-principle/ https://github.com/ardalis/cleanarchitecture It will be more amenable to DI then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

private string GetConnectionString()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    return Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

}
```

Remember appsetting.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=((local));Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;user id=xx;password=xxxx;"
  }
}
```

Comment: It works fine, but what if you want to have different connection string for different environment (Development/Production)?