# .net core, n-layered app, should services layer have dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core

**Straightforward question is**: are Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions meant to be used only within the context of umbrella app (web app in this case) or in class libraries also?

**Example:**

In a n-layered, asp.net core app we have services layer that is dependant on some settings coming from `appsettings.json` file.

What we first started with is something along these lines in Startup.cs:

```
  services.Configure<Services.Options.XOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.OptionProperty1 = Configuration["OptionXSection:OptionXProperty"];
  });
```

And then in service constructor:

```
ServiceConstructor(IOptions<XOptions> xOptions){}
```

But that assumes that in our Service layer we have dependecy on `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`.

We're not sure if this is recomended way or is there some better practice?

It just feels a bit awkward our services class library should be aware of DI container implementation.

Comment: it is perfectly legit to use IOptions wherever you find them useful in my opinion

Comment: what happens if you want to use your service tomorrow in some other umbrella app that uses some DI container other than .net core defaults one?

Comment: service class doesn't need to be aware of DI, it just has a consturcotr dependency, service itself should also be added by DI not newed up. DI works through all the layers

Comment: none of your classes should be aware of the DI container except Startup.cs where it is wired up you can easily switch to other DI containers instead of the default one. Having a constructor dependency doe snot imply awareness of DI

Comment: but but....Microsoft.Extensions.Options is a part of DI container implementation, isn't it? thus if you put that dependency in your services layer you effectively get service dependant on DI implementation.

Comment: no it can work with any DI container. ultimately even if you use a 3rd party DI the underlying framework populates the default DI and then the 3rd party one also collects those dependencies already added to the default DI and then takes over

Comment: IOptions is not really part of the DI system but is often used to wire up dependencies from the config system no matter which DI container is used

Comment: ok, let me put it the other way around: whatever you inject into service should be defined withinin that same service layer boundaries and not anywhere outside. if its outside, your service becomes aware of it and that pretty much breaks whole DI/IoC point.

Comment: not how I see it, to me the main web app is the composition root. The rest of my code typically goes in class libraries and everything for all layers gets wired up from startup. I do tend to encapsulate that stuff into extension methods but those get called from startup

Comment: Yes and no. Using `IOptions<T>` is not much different than creating your own injectable options and pass that around in your constructor. If it makes you sleep better, you can create your own `IInjectedSettings<T>` class which concrete implementation is inside your ASP.NET Core app and just wraps around `IOptions<T>` and requests it in it's constructor. Then your layer don't have any reference to `MS.E.Options` and when you change the app/composition root, you can replace it with any other system in charge

Comment: @TSeng, well its very different solely for the fact that my poco is defined within my service and IOptions is not. Its not about sleeping better, its about my service layer depend on my web app. Dont you think thats huge thing which go against while di/ioc point?

Comment: @Joe its not about startup, its about the dependencies flow. this way we have dependencies that should not exist in usual di setup.

Comment: `MS.E.Options` isn't part of the web application framework. You can also directly inject your poco class, but you need additional registration to do so. And you lose the advantage that the options get updated when you edit your appsettings.json. With plain poco injection, you need re restart your app. Without you can use `IOptionSnapshot<T>` to get automatically the new settings after editing appsettings.json (assuming you register your appsettings. with `reloadOnSave: true` parameter overload of `AddJsonFile`

Comment: @Tseng, yes i see your point. Hopefully, you also see where my uncomfortableness comes from. Could you please show how to register custom POCO for injection? And please do it in answer so i can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @deezg in 99.9% I don't need to reload the `appsettings.json`, so I don't use `IOptions<T>`. You could find a similar question conserning advantages and drawbacks of such approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679665/read-and-use-settings-from-appsettings-json-without-ioptionst

Comment: @Ilya great read! I ended up doing almost exactly the same thing. Good to see i am not going nuts having problem with IOptions dependency in my libraries;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register POCO settings for injection too, but you lose some functionalities related to when the `appsettings.json` gets edited.

```cs
services.AddTransient<XOptions>(
    provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<XOptions>>().Value);
```

Now when you inject `XOptions` in constructor, you will get the class. But when your edit your `appsettings.json`, the value won't be updated until the next time it's resolved which for scoped services would be on next request and singleton services **never**.

On other side injecting `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` `.Value` will always get you the current settings, even when `appsettings.json` is reloaded (assuming you registered it with `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnSave: true)`).

The obvious reason to keep the functionality w/o pulling `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` package into your service/domain layer will be create your own interface and implementation.

```cs
// in your shared service/domain assembly
public interface ISettingsSnapshot<T> where T : class
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

and implement it on the application side (outside of your services/domain assemblies), i.e. `MyProject.Web` (where ASP.NET Core and the composition root is)

```cs
public class OptionsSnapshotWrapper<T> : ISettingsSnapshot<T>
{
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<T> snapshot;

    public OptionsSnapshotWrapper(IOptionsSnapshot<T> snapshot) 
    {
        this.snapshot = snapshot ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(snapshot));
    }

    public T Value => snapshot.Value;
}
```

and register it as

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ISettingsSnapshot<>), typeof(OptionsSnapshotWrapper<T>));
```

Now you have removed your dependency on `IOptions<T>` and `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` from your services but retain all up advantages of it like updating options when appsettings.json is edited. When you change DI, just replace `OptionsSnapshotWrapper<T>` with your new implementation.