# How to pass a POCO class to .NET Core configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on integration tests of .NET Core application and want to use some test configuration. My configuration is a POCO class that is configured via `appsettings.json` and then consumed via `IOptions<T>`. In my tests I'd like to use an instance of that class.

Here is the code:

```
 var mySettings = GetTestSettings(); // factory method returning POCO class 
 var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

 // I am looking for something like 
 configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryObject("Settings", mySettings);

 // does not work, result is just string 
 configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection("Settings",
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mySettings)); 

// requires filename
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("filename.json");
```

What is the easiest way to feed POCO to configuration?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the settings e.g. use within another class, a controller etc.? Also is this POCO class used to store settings that are loaded from the appsettings.json file?

Comment: @SimplyGed updated my question.

Comment: Do you just want to pass the IOptions<T> to your class under test? This answer solves that https://stackoverflow.com/a/40898882/2309376

Comment: no, I am usint TestServer and this configuration should be injected into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

```
configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(ToDictionary(GetTestSettings()));

private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToDictionary(object o) => 
    AddPropsToDic(JObject.FromObject(o), new Dictionary<string, string>(), "Settings");

private static Dictionary<string, string> AddPropsToDic(JObject jo, Dictionary<string, string> dic, string prefix)
{
    jo.Properties()
        .Aggregate(dic, (d, jt) =>
        {
            var value = jt.Value;
            var key = $"{prefix}:{jt.Name}";

            if (value.HasValues)
                return AddPropsToDic((JObject) jt.Value, dic, key);

            dic.Add(key, value.ToString());
            return dic;
        });
    return dic;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`AddInMemoryCollection` takes a collection of `KeyValuePair` where a key is setting key and value is its value. This call from the question

```
configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection("Settings", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mySettings));
```

actually passes "Settings" as a key and whole JSON as one setting value, which expectedly does not work.

But the overall approach is correct, you should use `AddInMemoryCollection` extension call.  In collection passed to this call, setting keys are full paths within configuration, delimited by a colon. Say if you have following settings POCO:

```
public class SomeSettings
{
    public string SomeKey1 { get; set; }
    public int SomeKey2 { get; set; }
}
```

and it's loaded from following JSON

```
{
    "SomeSettings": {
        "SomeKey1": "SomeData",
        "SomeKey2": 123
    } 
}
```

the keys would be `SomeSettings:SomeKey1` and `SomeSettings:SomeKey2`.

You could then add such configuration with following `AddInMemoryCollection` call:

```
configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "SomeSettings:SomeKey1", "SomeData" },
    { "SomeSettings:SomeKey2", 123 },
});
```

Now, if you want to add settings POCO with one call, you could write simple extension method that will enumerate setting class properties using reflection and return collection of key-value pairs for properties names and values.

Here is a sample:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToKeyValuePairs(this Object settings, string settingsRoot)
    {
        foreach (var property in settings.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"{settingsRoot}:{property.Name}", property.GetValue(settings).ToString());
        }
    }
}

public static class ConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AddInMemoryObject(this ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, object settings, string settingsRoot)
    {
        configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(settings.ToKeyValuePairs(settingsRoot));
    }
}
```

In the test:

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
var mySettings = GetTestSettings();
configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryObject(mySettings, "Settings");
```

Such simple `ObjectExtensions.ToKeyValuePairs` extension method will work for plain POCO like `SomeSettings` above. However it will not work if some of the properties are also objects like here:

```
public class InnerSettings
{
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
}

public class OuterSettings
{
    public InnerSettings InnerSettings { get; set; }
}
```

However I believe you got an idea and could make required adjustments if required.

Comment: yes, thanks for you answer. In my case I have nested objects, so needed to add support for it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind an additional dependency, I created a package [Extensions.Configuration.Object](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.Configuration.Object/) just for this.

```
dotnet add package Extensions.Configuration.Object
```

And then you can do:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddObject(new // This supports anonymous and simple classes.
    {
        MyProperty = "MyValue",
        MySection = new 
        {
            MyOtherProperty = "MyOtherValue"
        }
    })
    .Build();
```

If you don't want an additional dependency, you can just copy source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/lawrence-laz/Extensions.Configuration.Object).

Comment: I like this answer it works in a general sense, I added a Quick and Dirty answer below, which I was please to see it performs just about as close.. you have me beat by memory allocation though :/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with the given answers [@the_joric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49385725/5963888) and [@codeFuller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384575/5963888) provided, and this is they mostly fall apart the second you put in an array, and also making sure you handle nested objects of course. [@Laurynas_Lazauskas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72242705/5963888) answer is actually the most correct and approached it by adding a Provider which is probably the best technical route to take. However if you are interested in a Quick and Dirty solution something like this could work, and its performance to @Laurynas_Lazauskas answer might as well be equal. The only feature I wish I could see is the ability to add in a root key.

---

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> CreateConfiguration<TObject>(this TObject @object, string rootKey = "")
    where TObject : class
{
    if( @object == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@object)); }
    var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> CreateConfiguration(object @obj, string key, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        foreach (var p in @obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && !typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
            { 
                return CreateConfiguration(p.GetValue(@obj), $"{key}{(String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? "" : ":")}{p.Name}", dict); 
            }
            else if(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach( var element in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)p.GetValue(@obj))
                {
                    d.TryAdd($"{key}{(String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? "" : ":")}{p.Name}:{i++}", element.ToString());
                }
            }
            d.TryAdd($"{key}{(String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? "" : ":")}{p.Name}", p.GetValue(@obj).ToString());
        }
        return dict;
    }

    return CreateConfiguration(@object, rootKey, d);
}
```

---

| Method | Job | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetConfiguration | .NET 5.0 | .NET 5.0 | 4.221 us | 0.0749 us | 0.0735 us | 0.85 | 0.02 | 1.1368 | 5 KB |
| GetConfiguration | .NET 6.0 | .NET 6.0 | 3.721 us | 0.0663 us | 0.0620 us | 0.75 | 0.02 | 1.1063 | 5 KB |
| GetConfiguration | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 | 4.972 us | 0.0960 us | 0.0851 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1.1292 | 5 KB |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GetConfiguration_AddObjectNuget | .NET 5.0 | .NET 5.0 | 6.800 us | 0.1170 us | 0.0977 us | 0.78 | 0.03 | 0.8621 | 4 KB |
| GetConfiguration_AddObjectNuget | .NET 6.0 | .NET 6.0 | 6.113 us | 0.1186 us | 0.1542 us | 0.71 | 0.03 | 0.7401 | 3 KB |
| GetConfiguration_AddObjectNuget | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 | 8.528 us | 0.1466 us | 0.3308 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1.0223 | 4 KB |