# What is the best option to Mock IOptions for getting configured data from secret.json file in dotnet core

Tags: .net

Here is the scenario-
I have users that I want to seed from a controller. I have configured default user creds in secret.json file, configured them in services and retrieve them in controller using IOption where T is the DefaultUserCred.cs
Now, I want to create xunit test for this.
What is the way to achieve this without configuring IService in Test unit.

```
here's code sample ---  
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly DefaultUserOptions _options;
        public SeedController(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IWebHostEnvironment env,
            IOptions<DefaultUserOptions> options
            )
        {
            _context = context;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _env = env;
            _options = options.Value;
        }
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateDefaultUsers()
        {
            string role_RegisteredUser = "RegisteredUser";
            string role_Administrator = "Administrator";
            if (await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role_RegisteredUser) ==
             null)
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new
                 IdentityRole(role_RegisteredUser));
            if (await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role_Administrator) ==
             null)
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new
                 IdentityRole(role_Administrator));
            var addedUserList = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            var email_Admin = _options.Admin_Email;
            if (await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email_Admin) == null)
            {
                var user_Admin = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    UserName = email_Admin,
                    Email = email_Admin,
                };
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user_Admin, _options.Admin_Password);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin,
                 role_RegisteredUser);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin,
                 role_Administrator);
                user_Admin.EmailConfirmed = true;
                user_Admin.LockoutEnabled = false;
                addedUserList.Add(user_Admin);
            }
            var email_User = _options.User_Email;
            if (await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email_User) == null)
            {
                var user_User = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    UserName = email_User,
                    Email = email_User
                };
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user_User, _options.User_Password);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_User,
                 role_RegisteredUser);
                user_User.EmailConfirmed = true;
                user_User.LockoutEnabled = false;
                addedUserList.Add(user_User);
            }
            if (addedUserList.Count > 0)
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return new JsonResult(new
            {
                Count = addedUserList.Count,
                Users = addedUserList
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Eventually, could you give some codes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are injecting services to controllers, you need to instantiate service in your test. Next, if you are asking for mocking IOption in test, for inject option to service, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40898882/4510954) you can find a solution.

Comment: Code added. @ElConrado